# Database connectivity with Access2007

Tags: c#-2.0

i want to know how to connect an Access 2007 database and retrieve data from that using C#.net2005. I don't know anything about database connectivity.Please help me i'm new in this.If u are busy to explain can u mention any good link to the tutorial for that

Answer (score 1):

Use an OleDbConnection, and learn ADO.NET: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/aa937699.aspx

Answer (score 1):

[C# How to connect to MS Access 2007](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/508345/c-how-to-connect-to-ms-access-2007) - you can find code example there.

Also you do the following.

Create a new winforms application.

- Go to Server Explorer (View->Server
  Explorer, Ctrl + Alt + S)

  There on server explorer, right click
  on data connections and add a data
  connection.

  Choose the Add Connection option.

  There change the Data source to
  Access Database.

  Open the mdb file you want to attach.
  It will generate its connection
  string automatically.

  Then you get to choose the tables you
  want to insert and the query to use.

  Just select the table and click on
  all fields.

  Once the connection is done, drag it
  and drop on the form. Visual Studio
  will generate the code behind for you
  automatically.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to connect to Access Database.

You have to follow the following steps:-

1) First add  "using System.Data.OleDb;" at to top of the CS file.

2) Create connection string and open connection.

For access 2007

```
string ConnStr = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=D:\abc.mdb;Jet OLEDB:Database Password=password";

OleDbConnection MyConn = new OleDbConnection(ConnStr);
```

3) Open this connection.

```
MyConn.Open();
```

4) Create object for command and reader to get the data from access database.

```
OleDbCommand Cmd =  new OleDbCommand(StrCmd, MyConn);;
OleDbDataReader ObjReader = Cmd.ExecuteReader();
```

5) Now look through the reader object to get the data

```
if (ObjReader != null)
{

}
```

6) After completing the processing

```
ObjReader.Close();
MyConn.Close();
```